# Pausing a $watch in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jphastings/ym4zY/); I have two sets of input boxes with scope variables attached via ng-model.

Think of this system like a google style search, with a single search box and an 'advanced search'.

- When the single search input is updated (in the example, `a`) then there is a function to update the relevant 'advanced' inputs. I've implemented this in `$scope.$watch('a', ... )`.
- When the 'advanced' search input are edited then the single input should also be updated (implemented in `$scope.$watch('b', ... )`.

Of course, these two will generate a feedback loop - `a` updates `b` then vice versa, ad infinitum - this is not good! I'd like to be able to issue a "pause the other watcher" command at the start of each of the watches above, then (after updating the other variable) issue a "restart the watcher" command, to prevent this.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Your demo doesn't generate an infinite loop.  It does execute the watch a few times, but that's just how the $digest cycle works in Angular.  Unless your two $watch statements are changing the value of `$scope.a` to different things each time, then you'll be fine.  Is your demo not doing exactly what you want already?

Comment: You don't have an infinite loop in there. The reason to this is that the $watch does not run inside of $apply, so $digest never happens and the other $watch does not get triggered. If you put a scope.$digest() after your assignment then you'd have an infinite loop. For more info see http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#runtime

Comment: From what you've said I reckon it's just that my function to go from A to B is not the reverse of the function to go from B to A, which is setting up a race condition. As AngularJS seems to be able to figure out the equalising situations, so I should be alright. -- I did try setting a 'lock' variable (If you edit A, a variable is set to true just before B is changed, and set to false afterwards; the watcher functions have an if clause preventing a backward alteration if the lock variable is true; but I think the asynchronous nature of Angular prevents this from working)

Answer (score 2):

I have put together a simple example.

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myTestCntrl">
    <input type="button" ng-click="increaseCounter()" value="Click me" /> clicked: {{counter}z} times<br/>
    <input type="button" ng-click="pauseWatcher()" value="{{watcherBtnText}}" /> watched: {{internalCounter}} times<br/>
    <strong>Number of $$watchers in $scope:</strong> {{$$watchers.length}}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('app', [])
            .controller('myTestCntrl', function myTestCntrl($scope) {
            $scope.counter = 0;
            $scope.pauseWatching = false;
            $scope.watcherBtnText = 'Pause';
            $scope.internalCounter = -1;
            $scope.increaseCounter = function() {
                $scope.counter++;
            };
            var listenerFn = function() {
                if ($scope.pauseWatching) {
                    namedWatcher();
                } else {
                    $scope.internalCounter++;
                };
            }
            var namedWatcher = $scope.$watch('counter', listenerFn);
            $scope.pauseWatcher = function() {
                if ($scope.pauseWatching) {
                    $scope.watcherBtnText = 'Pause';
                    $scope.pauseWatching = false;
                    $scope.internalCounter--;
                    namedWatcher = $scope.$watch('counter', listenerFn);
                } else {
                    $scope.watcherBtnText = 'Continue';
                    $scope.pauseWatching = true;
                    namedWatcher();
                };
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

**demo on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BuriB/63sND/**